# Equation of line

Tags: geometry

Suppose that you don't already know the equation of a line. You take two points A and B. You join those two points and extend that line indefinitely. Now consider any point on that line and mark it as (0,0). Draw your coordinate system accordingly and consider two quantites: r<sub>A</sub> and r<sub>B</sub>.

$A_y = r_AA_x$ 
$B_y = r_BB_x$ 
r<sub>A</sub> is always equal to r<sub>B</sub>!

Consider any other point on the line. The way Y is related to X is the same again!

How is this possible? Is there any proof? Can we surely say that all points that lie on the line have their Ys related to Xs in the same way? Is there no such point which does not have the same relation of its X and Y as the other points on the same line?

Comment: Use similar triangles. (BTW: You've rediscovered that the equation for any (non-vertical) line through the origin is $y=mx$ for some $m$. Congratulations! :) )

Comment: Wow, didn't notice the triangles formed. Searching for such stuff didn't yield any good results. Got my answer in a matter of minutes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Note that $\triangle OCA$ is similar to $\triangle ODB$

It follows that $\dfrac{A_y}{A_x} = \dfrac{B_y}{B_x}$